# The view orders.views.order_create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

The view orders.views.order_create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I tried everything and still get this error I think that the problem is with the urls but i am not sure.
This is the views.py for the order checkout.
I get the error when I click the checkout everything else is working and only the checkout is giving an error.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from .models import OrderItem
from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from cart.cart import Cart

def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart: 
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,product=item['product'],price=item['price'],quantity=item['quantity'])

                cart.clear()
                return render(request, 'orders/created.html', {'order': order})

    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'orders/create.html', {'cart': cart, 'form':form})
```

the base urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    url(r'^orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<product_id>[0-9a-f-]+)/$', views.detail, name="detail"),
]
```

and the order app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/$', views.order_create, name='order_create'),
]
```

the url in localhost should be 127.0.0.1:8000/orders/create
and the create.html and created.html are in the templates folder in the market folder. I would kindly provide any other information if needed to help me fix the bug.

Answer (score 4):

Your view returns a response only in the case where the method is `POST` which would correspond to the form submission.
You need to return a response when method is `GET` too, to display the form.

One solution could be:

```
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    form = OrderCreateForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=order,product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'],
                    quantity=item['quantity'])

            cart.clear()
            return render(request, 'orders/created.html', {'order': order})

    return render(request, 'orders/create.html', {'cart': cart, 'form':form})
```

where the second return will be hit if method is not `POST`, or if `form` is not valid. (I'm not sure what `Cart` is, so I don't know if it should be sent on a `GET` response...)

Comment: Can you show me a solution for that because it should be running properly with the else statement.

Comment: With the current indentation, the else is for the case where the form is not valid. Not when method is not `POST`. You need to return a response in all the situations.

Comment: Oh it really was the indentation I think i got it right but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be with improper indentation

```
def order_create(request):
  cart = Cart(request)
  if request.method == 'POST':
```

At the moment it's like

```
 def order_create(request):
      cart = Cart(request)
 if request.method == 'POST':
```

Comment: It is not from the indentation it will give an indentation error

Answer (score 0):

Edit your view may be somewhat like this, check your indentations first,

```
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,product=item['product'],price=item['price'],quantity=item['quantity'])

            cart.clear()

    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'orders/create.html', {'cart': cart, 'form':form})
```

Comment: The indentation is not a problem